# How to crawl the contents from all the next page links using beautiful soup and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have coded a web crawler which crawls the name and prices from first page of the search results. I have got to click the next page link to reach the next page using selenium webdriver but I am not sure where to put in the code for the next page links and call that for scraping the content from all the next pages. Please help

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re
import time
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import sys;
reload(sys);
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")


class Agoda(CrawlSpider):
name = 'agoda'
allowed_domains = ["agoda.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.agoda.com"] 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.agoda.com")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_area_promo_HomeSearchBox1_TextSearch1_searchText").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_area_promo_HomeSearchBox1_TextSearch1_searchText").send_keys("Mumbai")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[contains(@id,'ddlCheckInDay')]")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(.,'Mon 23')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_area_promo_HomeSearchBox1_SearchButton").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentMain_rptAB1936_ctl01_rptSearchResultAB1936_ctl01_lnkResult1936").click()
#driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentMain_rptSearchResult_ctl01_lnkResult").click()
time.sleep(40);
#print driver.page_source
TotalResults = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='blue ssr_search_text']")
print TotalResults.text

html_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source) 





names = soup("a", {"class":"hot_name"})

prices = soup("span", {"class":"fontxlargeb purple"})

hotel_names = [name[1].get_text() for name in enumerate(names)] #or [name[1].get_text() for name in enumerate(names)]
prices = [price[1].get_text() for price in enumerate(prices)] 


name_price_list = itertools.izip_longest(hotel_names, prices)

for name, price in name_price_list:
    print name, price   

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'Next page >')]").click() #next page link
```

I have this webdriver code of next page link  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(.,'Next page >')]").click()
but dont know where to put it and make a loop so that the crawler go through all tha pages and extract the prices and names

Comment: Have you tried http://scrapy.org/? Crawling with Selenium isn't a good thing at all.

Comment: Or alternatively http://pypi.python.org/pypi/spyda (*relatively new and used at my workplace to crawl links and metadata from websites*).

Comment: If there's no contents generated by AJAX in the page, using selenium to fetch a page is not a proper decision because it is slow and consumes much resource. Just try `scrapy` to crawl pages. And if you want to use the **headless browser** technique, use [Phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) instead.

Comment: I did tried scrapy but the content generated are ajax driven So I have to use both selenium and beautifulsoup.